# How to read Post Parameters from Payment Gateway API After Successful Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

I am using a Payment Gateway Which will send the response to the Success page. Their documentation indicates they are sending response as POST parameters. I tried to Read these parameters but i am not able to get the parameters. I had sent a mail to support and they said they will send the data from their server to our server prior redirection to success page. I implemented my code in success page. Where I should Implement and how to save these values in my code for further use.

My code is Here

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            /// store all the posted form variables in an object to use later
            response notifyresponse = new response();
            notifyresponse.CreditVouchersTransactionId = Request["CreditVouchersTransactionId"];

            notifyresponse.MerchantName = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["MerchantName"]);
            notifyresponse.AmountToPay = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["AmountToPay"]);

            notifyresponse.PaymentOKURL = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["PaymentOKURL"]);
            notifyresponse.OrderId = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["OrderId"]);
            notifyresponse.AmountCurrency = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["AmountCurrency"]);
            notifyresponse.PaymentType = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["AmountType"]);
            notifyresponse.PaymentStatus = GetFormVariableOrNull(Request["PaymentStatus"]);

            string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                Session["amountpay"]=keys[i]   ;
            }
}





protected string GetFormVariableOrNull(object formvariable)
    {
        if (formvariable != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return formvariable.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /// log the exception in file or DB
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);/// just for an example
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
            return null;


    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler, it will show you all the traffic going back forth and provide a more accurate picture as to whats going on between those transactions

https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

---

## Edit

A HTTP message can be composed of two part, first is the header, the other is the body.

When making a GET request to a server, it won't contain a body. A POST request on the other hand, will. There are line breaks in between the headers and the body... I've demonstrated a POST request below

[image]

Comment: i downloaded fiddler just now. i don't know how to use it can you please tell me where i will find the post parameters

Comment: Thanks for reply. Are you showing images for sending POST data to server from our side. but i want the data i am getting from server can you please suggest me how i will get